# Updated AWS CLI and now sync doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So Amazon Web Service (AWS) has just upgraded their CLI to v2. I've updated my version to the latest (and checked with aws --version to make sure it's using it). Trouble is, now my simple command doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

With CLI v1, I used: `aws s3 sync myfile s3bucket`
This worked fine and I had no issues with it.

Now, with CLI v2, it throws this error:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: paths
```

I've looked up the documentation and the only mention of "paths" is this:

```
Options
*******

"paths" (string)
```

Literally just that. Any idea what this paths option (that is seemingly not an option, but a required parameter) does? And how then do I get aws s3 sync to start working again on this new CLI version?

Very disgruntled right now. I had just got this app working, sent it to a coworker to test it and bam! Broken!

Edit2: On checking the path files,  I've realised the mistake. Each new subfolder I added to path adds the \ AFTER the folder, thus ending on the folder "CloudSync\Data" for example. It's not the updated CLI that's messing things up (although it was the update message that broke my program on my coworkers pc). It was that darned \
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: What are the actual arguments `myfile` and `s3bucket`, are there protocols mentioned in them, are they encapsulated in `"`s, whitespaces, ...

Comment: When referring to Amazon S3, use the `s3://` prefix. For example: `s3://my-bucket/my-folder/foo.txt`

Comment: Okay looking back at my path files I've realised my mistake. Each new subfolder added to path adds the \ AFTER the folder, thus ending on the folder "CloudSync\Data\". It's not the updated CLI that's messing things up (although it was the update message that broke my program on my coworkers pc). It was that darned \
Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sync command can be used to sync two PATHS.. Possibilities are as follows :

```
 <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
```

i.e. syncing localpath to S3; OR S3 to Local; OR two S3 paths itself.

There are some changes in v2. I executed on my local system and made sure this is working fine: Basically LocalPath should be a folder ; and no longer just a file. So that it will sync all contents inside temp folder in this example.

```
aws s3 sync temp s3://datalake-dl/
```

Comment: Okay looking back at my path files I've realised my mistake. Each new subfolder added to path adds the \ AFTER the folder, thus ending on the folder "CloudSync\Data\". It's not the updated CLI that's messing things up (although it was the update message that broke my program on my coworkers pc). It was that darned \
Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's comment on the accepted answer was my problem too.

This fails with the error "the following arguments are required: paths"

`aws s3 sync 'C:\my-folder\' s3://my-bucket-my-folder/`

This succeeds

`aws s3 sync 'C:\my-folder' s3://my-bucket-my-folder`